# Customize angular chart tooltip

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart, chart.js2

I am using [Angular Chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) and I need to customize tooltip.

Currently tooltip on pie chart show like this. They are overlapping too.

[image: CaptureChartPie]

I need to show tooltips something similar to this.

[image: CaptureChartPieNew]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I don't think this will be an easy task, as chart.js uses the canvas to render the charts. So you can't easily adapt the styles of the tooltips...